# Числовые ряды C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, ряды

Есть задание

> Для каждого x, изменяющегося от a до b с шагом h, найти значения
>   функ-ции Y(x), суммы S(x) и |Y(x)–S(x)| и вывести в виде таблицы.
>   Значения a, b, h и n вводятся с клавиатуры.  Так как значение S(x)
>   является рядом разложения функции Y(x), при пра-вильном решении
>   значения S и Y для заданного аргумента x (для тестовых значе-ний
>   исходных данных) должны совпадать в целой части и в первых
>   двух-четырех позициях после десятичной точки.  Работу программы
>   проверить для a = 0,1; b = 1,0; h = 0,1; значение парамет-ра n выбрать
>   в зависимости от задания (10, 20, 50, 100).
>
> [image: вот такой ряд]

Не сходятся цифры, видит может кто ошибку? Помогите пожалуйста!

```
{
    double a, b, h, x, y, s, r;
    int k, n, zn;

    a = StrToFloat(Edit1->Text);
    h = StrToFloat(Edit2->Text);
    b = StrToFloat(Edit3->Text);
    n = StrToFloat(Edit4->Text);

    for (x = a; x <= b; x += h)
    {
        s = 1;
        r = 1;
        zn = -1;

        for (k = 1; k <= n; k++)
        {
            r *= zn * ((x * x) / (2 * k + 2));
            s += r;
        }

        y = sin(x);
        Memo1->Lines->Add("яЁш x= " + FloatToStrF(x, ffFixed, 8, 2) +
                          " ёєььр S(x)= " + FloatToStrF(s, ffFixed, 8, 6) + " Y(x)= "
                          + FloatToStrF(y, ffFixed, 8, 6));
    }
}
```

Comment: Знак тоже в степень возводить надо. Ой, там полный мрак. Вы вообще в школе, простите, учились? Ведь ни для кого не секрет, что 24 = 4!

Comment: да 17 лет назад. И только сегодня начал вспоминать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не те первые члены ряда (первый член не 1, а `x`), не на тот знаменатель делите:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И еще - этот ряд сходится к синусу, а не к косинусу. Вы точно привели в условии верный ряд?

Вот, в консольном, так сказать, варианте:

```
int main()
{
    double
        a = 0.0,
        b = 1.6,
        h = 0.1;
    int n = 5;

    for(double x = a; x <= b; x+= h)
    {
        double sum = x, term = x, x2 = x*x;
        for(int k = 1; k <= n; ++k)
            sum += term *= -x2/(2*k*(2*k+1));
        printf("%.3lf   %8.5lf   %8.5lf\n",x,sum,sin(x));
    }

}
```

А вот - для косинуса:

```
for(double x = a; x <= b; x+= h)
{
    double sum = 1, term = 1, x2 = x*x;
    for(int k = 1; k <= n; ++k)
        sum += term *= -x2/(2*k*(2*k-1));
    printf("%.3lf   %8.5lf   %8.5lf\n",x,sum,cos(x));
}
```

**Update**
Раз все так непонятно...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за помощь.  Еще вопрос, если не сложно, можете объяснить, как вы пришли к данному выражению? Как правильно разложить факториал в данном выражение?

Comment: И почему a*(k-1)?

Comment: Ну записал член `a_k = (-1)^k * x^(2k+1)/(2k+1)!`, такой же для `k-1`, поделил, сократил...

Comment: См. обновленный ответ

Comment: Просто везде пишут, что нужно брать следующий член числового ряда k+1. И у меня получается ((2(k+1)+1))!

Comment: Ну если вам нужны именно шашечки, а не ехать - берите `k` и `k+1`, только потом, когда считать будете, не забывайте, что вычисляете не `a_k`, а `a_{k+1}`... Мне проще так, как я делаю, чтоб потом не думать, что в цикле индекс `k`, а считаю я другой член, а..... - результат-то будет один и тот же.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое еще раз!!! Буду разбираться. Тяжело вспоминать просто это все, а хочется понять.

Comment: Я вот одного не могу понять мы вроди ищем сумму членов ряда, а по факту получается отношение между a_k  и a_k-1. Повторюсь учился почти двадцать лет назад, если я Вам еще не надоел напишите пожалуйста.

Comment: Отношение - просто для вычисления очередного члена. Чтоб не считать его с нуля, а получить умножением на быстро вычисляемое значение (`term *= .....`). А сумма ищется, как положено - добавлением этого вновь вычисленного члена (`sum += ....`). Конечно же, можно делать долго и странно: `term = znak * pow(x,2*k+1)/factorial(2*k+1)` - но *зачем*? Это как минимум неэффективно...

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное！